# Change the directory where the script resides in

Tags: bash

I'm trying to change the directory name where the BASH script resides in.

I've built following function inside this script:

```
function rename_dir(){
  echo "Gimme new dir name: "
  read new_dir_name
  mv ../${PWD##*/} ../$new_dir_name
  cd ../$new_dir_name
```

Basically it does the job.
When I run it manually by calling `./script.sh` it changes the directory name but since it's running in a subshell - I need to do:

```
cd ..
cd New_Dir_name
```

And that's fine and understandable. No biggie.

When I source the script it naturally does the job but when I rename the directory the script loses the 'X' attribute and I need to `chmod` it again.

Any other approach to overcome this? Anyone has any other ideas how to get it done properly?

Comment: Remove the `cd`. You don't have to `cd` after changing the name, only the name changed, not the directory.

Comment: You're right. Damn!
So the ```cd``` was causing the loss of 'X' attribute? Why?